# GDI+: How do I draw a line that's one inch in length on any device it's drawn on?

Tags: .net, graphics, gdi+

I need to draw a line one inch long on any device given a `Graphics` reference to it. I need it to be an inch long regardless of what `Transform` is set to. Let's assume that the scaling factor of the transform is given by `scale` in both horizontal and vertical directions.

Some C++/CLI code:

```
g->DrawLine(Pens::Black, 50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f + oneInchEquivalent / scale, 50.0f);
```

Now that was not difficult at all! Now all we need to do is calculate `oneInchEquivalent`.

`g->DpiX` gives me a distance of what looks like one inch on screen but not on the printer. It seems that on printers, drawing a line of 100 units with `g->PageUnit` set to GraphicsUnit::Display will give me a line one inch long. But, I really need this to work regardless of the `PageUnit` setting. In fact, changing `PageUnit` will change the width of the pen!!

**Edit:** I have tentatively accepted the only answer here as it's pretty close to what I am looking for.

Comment: I updated my answer now with a print sample

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer became rather long after a couple of edits, so here is the final result:

Setting the `PageUnit` property of the `Graphics` object to `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` and taking in multiplying coordinates with the DpiX and DpiY values will render the expected result on both display and printer devices.

```
private static void DrawInchLine(Graphics g, Color color, Point start, Point end)
{
    GraphicsUnit originalUnit = g.PageUnit;
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(color, 1))
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen,
            start.X * g.DpiX,
            start.Y * g.DpiY,
            end.X * g.DpiX,
            end.Y * g.DpiY);
    }
    g.PageUnit = originalUnit;
}
```

You can have it paint on a Form (or some control):

```
using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    Point start = new Point(1, 1);
    Point end = new Point(2, 1);
    DrawInchLine(g, Color.Black, start, end);
}
```

...or send the output to a printer:

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings = dialog.PrinterSettings;
    pd.PrintPage += (psender, pe) =>
    {
        Point start = new Point(1, 1);
        Point end = new Point(2, 1);
        DrawInchLine(pe.Graphics, Color.Black, start, end);
        pe.HasMorePages = false;
    };

    pd.Print();
}
```

This does, however, rely on setting the `PageUnit`.

Comment: You can try CutePDF for a printer emulator. You can see the differences there.

Comment: I just realized I have a printer standing here; tried to print on it; came out at exactly one inch. Will update with the code.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, but I need to do this using Math alone, without changing the PageUnit setting. Changing PageUnit will affect the width of the pen. See the last part of my question.

Comment: Ah, missed that part... Unfortunately I cannot see a simple solution, apart from using `Pixel` as base unit for all drawing and scaling it to the target device using `DpiX` and `DpiY`.